# How do I access flashvars if I can't access the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flashvars, osmf, strobe-media-playback

How do I access flashvars if I can't access the stage?

I'm fiddling with the `Open Source Media Framework`'s `Strobe Media Playback` player, and I'm trying to take a flashvar and put it in the `package org.osmf.net.NetNegotiator`.

But the `netNegotiator` class can't access the `stage`, so I can't do `stage.loaderInfo.parameters` to get the flashvar.

---

Alternately, I can get the flashvar from `StrobeMediaPlayback.as`, but I can't figure out how to send it over there.

I've tried to import the package in the `StrobeMediaPlayback.as`, but not only does `NetNegotiator` show up on the predictive typing thing, I get an `undefined` error when I try to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always make a singleton class, something like SeesionFlashVars.as

```
package
{
    public class SeesionFlashVars
    {
        public static var flashVars:Object;
    }
}
```

Now, in your main class you can write the data in the static variable like this:

```
SessionFlashVars.flashVars = YOUR_OBJECT;
```

After that you can access the data same way in any of your classes.

Comment: This almost worked, except that the code where I want to send the singleton is in a different project. I think now I need to ask another question about how to get information from one `package` to another.

Comment: here's my new question, if you want to take a crack at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18408294/sending-information-to-a-library

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
var paramObj:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;

for (keyStr in paramObj) {
  valueStr = String(paramObj[keyStr]);
  tf.appendText("\t" + keyStr + ":\t" + valueStr + "\n");
}
```